# Trying to simplify boolean algebra a+ac+ab

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to simplify A+AC+AB.
I think I have solved it, but I want to double check its right, can it be simplified to A+A(C+b) and then again to A(C+B) as A+A = A?

Comment: A(1+C+B) = A(1)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} A+AC+AB & = A1+AC+AB \\
& = A(1+C+B) \\
& = A(1) \\
& = A 
\end{align}$$

Instead of doing $A+A=1$ you can use distributive law as you can see above in the second step.

**Note:** You have simplified the expression to $A(C+B)$ but the simplest form is $A$.